# Alert Policies keep incidents open after fix the uptime checks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, monitoring

I'm experiencing since past 9.Jun.21 a problem with the GCP Alert Policies that after the uptime checks recover the OK status, the Alert Policy keeps triggered as active.

The Alerts were configured time ago and the Uptime Checks appear all in green but I have 7 incidents open already since this date.

Is anybody else experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your case seems to be as described below, which if the case, it is an expected behavior that cause your incidents to be closed after 7 days.

[Partial metric data](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#partial-metric-data): Missing or delayed metric data can result in policies not alerting and incidents not closing. Delays in data arriving from third-party cloud providers can be as high as 30 minutes, with 5-15 minute delays being the most common. A lengthy delay—longer than the duration window—can cause conditions to enter an "unknown" state. When the data finally arrives, Cloud Monitoring might have lost some of the recent history of the conditions. Later inspection of the time-series data might not reveal this problem because there is no evidence of delays once the data arrives

Sometimes happenes that, in the vent of an outage beyond 30 minutes (as mentioned above), your alerting policy enter in such mentioned “unknown” state, resulting in the metrics reporting completely dropped (disappeared), causing that monitoring lost track of the history condition. Once recovered, by default it keeps the last readable value, which in this case, as the metric reporting stopped at all, the tool consider it a null value which is translated to a 0.000.

Such unknown state behavior causes the tool to “observe no changes” even though the metrics are reporting back to a normal state and pace, this enforce a “7 days no observable change” policy that you can read here [Managing incidents](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#incident): Incidents will be automatically closed if the system observed that the condition stopped being met or 7 days passed without an observation that the condition continued to be met.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jaime. In this case the metrics have been collected GCP internally from a cloud function consuming services running on GCP for the past two years, I'm measuring the latency of these monitors and they are ever under 900ms with an average of 300ms not checking within the same region. 
Must be something else beside this partial metric data glitch.